# How to select every row as an element in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function in matlab which accepts a nx1 matrix.

I have a matrix X of nx2 dims

How do I send matrix X to the function where every row of X goes as an element?

Comment: Having re-read your question can you clarify it a bit? Do you really mean that each row of `X` should go to the function, it would seem more appropriate to pass each *column* of `X` to the function.

Comment: the columns are restricted to 1, so I want to combine the 2 columns

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean you "want to combine the 2 columns"? Does my answer give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [matrix indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) article on the MathWorks website for information and examples of indexing matrices. To select rows from a matrix you can do something like the following:

```
>> m = rand(5, 2)

m =

    0.8147    0.0975
    0.9058    0.2785
    0.1270    0.5469
    0.9134    0.9575
    0.6324    0.9649

>> m(1,:)        

ans =

    0.8147    0.0975

>> m(end,:)      

ans =

    0.6324    0.9649
```

The first index of a matrix corresponds to the *rows*, the second corresponds to the *columns*. Here the `:` as the second index selects all the columns of the appropriate row. If you have a function `func`, and the matrix `m` from above you can pass each row of `m` to `func` as follows:

```
for i = 1:length(m)
    func(m(1,:)')
end
```

Note the transpose, which converts each row of `m` into a `2x1` array, i.e. a column vector, rather than a row vector.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have to do something like

```
for i=1:size(X,1)

  f(X(i,:)');

end
```

which means that you pass each row to the function `f` sequentially, transposed as a column vector.

If instead you want to linearize `X` on rows, you must do the following:

```
Xlin = reshape(X',numel(X),1);
f(Xlin);
```